# XAMPP MySQL not working on startup

Tags: mysql, xampp

```
10:01:04 PM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:01:04 PM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:01:04 PM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:01:04 PM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:01:04 PM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:01:04 PM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
10:01:04 PM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

I get this error when trying to start MySQL in xampp. Here is the mysql_error.log file:

```
31127 21:56:14 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131127 21:56:14 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
131127 21:56:15  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
131127 21:56:16 InnoDB: 5.5.32 started; log sequence number 22856689
131127 21:56:16 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
131127 21:56:16 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
131127 21:56:16 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may be the port that MySQL is trying to listen to is already used.  You can try going to the command prompt and run netstat to see what programs are using which ports.

```
C:\> netstat -a -b
```

Comment: None. There are no ports using port 3306. Even if I change the config to a different port like 2342. It still does not work.